# Calculating the sum of digits times the length of string

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm, loops

Last week i had a project from my teacher asking me to develop a program which takes in a string (stream of integers to be precise) and calculates the sum of the numbers in the string for each number in the string ie.

if input is 31456

- 1st loop does nothing (no number to left of 3 with result of sum as 0)
- 2nd loop ends on 3 (with result of sum as 3)
- 3rd loop ends on 1 (with result of 3+1 = 4)
- 4th loop ends on 4 (with result of 3+1+4 = 8)
- 5th loop ends on 5 (with result of 3+1+4+5 = 13)
- 6th loop ends on 6 (with result of 3+1+4+5+6 = 19)

I did submit a working project but it is full of spaghetti code (nested loops which ends if string length is less than the number of loops) which is not a clean approach. I wondered and studied a quite a lot over this situation in vain. I have not found any way of doing this without nested for loops in C (or maybe i gave up too fast ?)

Again, i am not asking you guys for an answer to my problem but wanted to know if there is a way of doing this without the nested loops (which will have problem if length of input > number of nested loops).

Comment: You SHOULD post the spaghetti code to let others know what you have tried

Comment: Why nested loops ? It looks like you need only one

Comment: @ziu , nested loops would be required like

for i; i<strlen; i++
// This loop goes through each digit in the stream
for j; j<i; j++
// This loop goes through each digit before the digit at "i" in the stream

So for 20 digits, i required 20 nested for loops, it works though but is as i said unrequired complication.

Comment: @user1075375 there's no reason to move back and forth in the number stream

Comment: This should be very simple and straight-forward. If you're struggling, step back and think about the flow logic of the program for a bit. (There should be one single loop, and it should be `while (std::cin >> n)`.)

Comment: Since this is clearly a training lesson context matters a lot; what are you supposed to learn/train? To understand and and break a problem down into an algorithm? To exactly follow specifications/instructions? Or proof that your solution is equivalent, i.e. meets the specification? Or a specific part of the algorithm, e.g. how to handle the n-loop-and-a-half "problem"? Or ...

Comment: I can't help you understand anything here unless I first see how you've failed.

Comment: It's not that i have failed, i was just wondering if there exists better solutions to this problem as my program will go through n-loops for n-times for a string of length n, also if n > number of nested loops in my code, it fails. (somewhat like next_permutation api in C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my advice: stop thinking in "loops" and start thinking in "steps". If the input string has `n` characters, you have `n+1` steps.

Now, ponder the following three questions:

1. Do you know the solution to the first step (no digits)?
2. Given the solution to step `k`, how can you compute the solution to step `k+1`?
3. How can you combine questions 1 and 2 to solve your entire problem with just a single loop?

Since this is homework, I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: In other words, think about how to reuse the result of step k in step k+1

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting you right

```
double temp = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)  // str is your complete number
{
   temp += Convert.ToDouble(str[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That calculates just the sum of digits (ie, total = 19 as in my example), i require the result of sum at every digit (ie, the 3,4,8,13,19 as calculated in my example)

Comment: save it as array and can be used.

Comment: IF you need to store the sum at each digit and I understood you correctly, then store intermediate sums in another vector, i.e.:
`double result = new double[str.size()]; 
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)  // str is your complete number, use std::vector::size() for C++
{
   temp += str[i];
   result[i] = temp;
}
delete result; // do not forget to free array from memory`

Comment: Or simpler yet, just output the subtotals as you go.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo-code:

```
array of sums
sums[0] = 0;              // That first time that you want to get 0!!
for i = 1 to length of str
    sums[i] <- sums[i-1] + str[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(const char ch){
    static int sum = 0;
    int retValue = sum;

    sum += ch -'0';

    return retValue;
}

int main(){
    char nums[] = "314156";/* "31456" ? */
    int size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(char);
    int i;

    for(i=0 ; i< size ; ++i){
        printf("%d time loop sum is %d\n", i+1, sum(nums[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**DEMO**

```
1 time loop sum is 0
2 time loop sum is 3
3 time loop sum is 4
4 time loop sum is 8
5 time loop sum is 9
6 time loop sum is 14
7 time loop sum is 20
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a C++ Standard Library function called `partial_sum()` that performs the series of sums you describe in a single pass over the input.

```
int sums[] = { 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 6 };

std::partial_sum(sums, sums + 7, sums);

// The results are left in sums[0]..sums[6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


static void printResults(int* results,int size);
int main( int argc, char** argv ){
    char nums[] = "314156";/* "31456" ? */
    int i,tmp;
    char tmpc[2];
    int length=strlen(nums);
    #define LENGTH length
    int results[LENGTH];
    results[0]=0;
    tmpc[0]=nums[0];
    sscanf(tmpc, "%d", &tmp);
    results[1]=tmp;
    int result=results[1];
    for(i=2 ; i< length ; ++i){
            tmpc[0]=nums[i];
            sscanf(tmpc, "%d", &tmp);
            result+=tmp;
            results[i]=result;
    }
    printResults(results,length);
    return 0;
}

static void printResults(int* results,int size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
       printf("%d time loop sum is %d\n", i+1,results[i]);
    }

}
```

This is a really basic and understandable code in C for beginner and the ouput is:

[image: output]

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
const int SIZE=10;
char myArray[SIZE];
int length=0,sum=0;
cout<<"enter Array of digit from 1-9\n\n ";
cin>>myArray;
cout<<myArray<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<myArray[i];i++)
{
    if(!isspace(myArray[i]))
    //if(myArray[i]!=NULL)

    length++;
}
    cout<<length<<endl;


for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    sum+=myArray[i]-'0';

}



    cout<<sum;
    }
```